# UIWebView and UIScrollView scrolling behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

This might be a stupid question, but I inserted a webview in a scroll view, and unfortunately both the scrollview and the webview don't move fluently when touched like in Safari. How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to make them scroll and zoom more fluently? Sorry for my spelling but I'm not [a native English speaker]. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "more fluently"? You shouldn't place the UIWebView within your UIScrollView. UIWebView allows zooming, scrolling, panning, etc.

Comment: Why are you putting a webView within a scrollView? The webView will scroll automatically.

Comment: I have read over and over again that one should avoid this, perhaps even in Apple's docs.  Check out http://dbrajkovic.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/load-images-asynchronously-in-a-uitableview-using-gcd-grand-central-dispatch/  Perhaps it might help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to move more fluently, you can probably reduce the contents of the websites. In my experience `UIWebView`s are really heavy objects (memory and processor wise talking). As far as I know, Apple is been trying to achieve a better performance of the class. I can't imagine a simple solution for this problem. Even loading a single `UIWebView` is not that *easy* for the OS. But I could be wrong ...

BTW: A `UIWebView` already implements a `UIScrollView`, though it is not actually a subclass and it conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocols.

Comment: Ok thanks. Hope apple makes a less heavy object than the UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

[`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is allready a subclass of [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) so you shouldn't use `UIScrollView` class again. Use delgete methods of `UIWebView`.

Comment: No, I used both because I wanted to incorporate more webviews in the scroll view

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that? Putting UIWebViews within UIScrollViews seems like a disaster waiting to happen.  Your user might not appreciate it.

Comment: By more fluently I mean loading faster the graphics.

Comment: It is not a subclass, it conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.